# How to get P-value for samples in 2-dimensional dataset?

Tags: python, p-value

[image: Example data plotted]

For a value in some 2 dimensional dataset, I would like to know how to calculate the p-value of any sample. Which steps do I have to take in order to calculate p-values for the data points?
Any help would be greatly appreciated, preferably with an example so it is easier to understand.
Thank you!

Comment: Are you asking for an algorithm/how to do it mathematically? Or are you asking how to code it? If the former, this question would be better suited for [stats.se] (but only if you provide more detail on your data). If the latter, please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] showing sample input, expected output, and code for what you've tried based on your own research